# Django REST framework export to json

Tags: json, api, csv, django-rest-framework

So I'm new to Django REST framework I used it on an app called ***Myana EDMS***. I want to export all the data from the ***API*** to the ***CSV*** file so I can upload it to Wordpress.

The **GET** looks like this `http://X.X.X.X/api/documents/37/metadata/` I have around 6000 documents and I want them all in one json file.

Answer (score 0):

Create a serializer specifying all the fields you need, then setup a ListView and the corresponding URL, then visit the URL and you should have your JSON. e.g.

```
# serializers.py
class DocumentSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Document
        fields = ('field1', 'field2') # etc. for all fields

# views.py
class DocumentListView(ListAPIView):
    queryset = Document.objects.all() # or whatever queryset has your 6,000 documents
    serializer = DocumentSerializer(queryset, many=True)
```